# Whats the unit (bytes, MB, ...) that this python function returns?

Tags: python, memory, operating-system, ram

Very quick question. I've been using this function in python to get RAM usage:

```
total_memory, used_memory, free_memory = map(int, os.popen('free -t -m').readlines()[-1].split()[1:])
```

Do you know if the answer it gives back is in bytes or MB or something else?

Comment: This is what `free -t -m` outputs, this has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: it is python. source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python/

Comment: It's Python that's executing the `free -t -m` shell command. So it returns whatever that command returns.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html

Answer (score 0):

From the man page for [free](http://Read%20the%20%5Bman%20page%5D(https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html)%20it):

> `-m, --mebi`
> Display the amount of memory in mebibytes.

So it's in mebibytes.